# Simultaneously applying for Schengen and UK tourist visas as an Indian citizen

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, indian-citizens

I am planning to go to UK and visit European countries on visitor visa, can we apply visa simultaneously in one application ?

Comment: At the moment this is only possible in China, UKVI has not announced any expansion of the pilot yet.  And the pilot itself is UK/Schengen via Belgium so there's a lot of work yet to do before all the members come online.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you can, as you will need to surrender your passport for each visa application.

Unless there is an exception (apparently, such an exception exists in China), you will have to apply for one, receive your passport, then apply for the other.

Answer (score 1):

NO.

Once you get your UK multiple-entry visa, you can use it to go to Ireland (including Northern Ireland) and Scotland. But, you can NOT use it to enter Schengen countries. You will need to apply for Schengen visa separately. See [Main Destination to apply for Schengen visa - Indian Citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64835/schengen-visa-what-qualifies-as-main-destination/64880#64880) to determine which consulate you should apply for a Schengen visa.

Comment: I think the OP know that he needs separate visas. The question is about whether it's possible to apply for both at the same time.